# Terminal says Twilio is installed; IDLE won't run it

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

It seems like I have twilio installed. From my terminal:

```
sudo easy_install twilio
```

> Password:
>   Searching for twilio
>   Best match: twilio 6.3.dev0
>   Processing twilio-6.3.dev0-py2.7.egg
>   twilio 6.3.dev0 is already the active version in easy-install.pth
>
> Using /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/twilio-6.3.dev0-py2.7.egg
>   Processing dependencies for twilio
>   Finished processing dependencies for twilio"

yet when I try testing the installation with:

```
from twilio.rest import TwilioRestClient

account_sid = "{{SK5f7498ffc677d5071f1e8505f622e04d}}" # Your Account SID from www.twilio.com/console
auth_token = "{{4xhl9pCzyd1oO5VRiMvWq9lIaiVgkvKd}}" # Your Auth Token from www.twilio.com/console

client = TwilioRestClient(account_sid, auth_token)

message = client.messages.create(body="My name is Ron Burgandry?",
    to="+16509954344", # Replace with your phone number
    from_="+16504828319") # Replace with your Twilio number

print(message.sid)
```

I get the following error:

> traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/Users/jonathangheller/Documents/send_text.py", line 1, in 
>       from twilio.rest import TwilioRestClient
>   ImportError: No module named 'twilio'"

Comment: Any particular reason you aren't using pip install? https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/python

Comment: I get a command not found error and the documentation recommends in this case to use easy_install

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do in your terminal is

```
pip3 install twilio --upgrade
```

add the "upgrade" if pip is already installed. If it is not installed install pip first and then run the above command. This fixed the issue for me.

The reason I was getting this error was that my Idle was running python 3.5.2 whereas the terminal was running python 2.7.1. If I changed the version of python on the terminal using python3 to version 3.5.1, import twilio command gave the above error. This problem was fixed by the above command.